# Rename multiple directories inserting between

Tags: bash, shell-script, rename

I have hundreds of directories that I need to rename, as follows:

```
from 15_öblös to 15_adj_öblös
from 14_kies to 14_adj_kies
and so on...
```

So, I have to insert 'adj' between the number and the word.

What I have done, but it's not doing well

```
for dic in [0-9]*
do
m=`echo "$dic" | cut -d"_" -f1`
l=`echo "$dic" | cut -d"_" -f2`
mv "$dic" "${m}_adj_${l}"
done
```

Comment: What's going wrong? Your script seems OK...

Comment: too complexe solution... try the solution I gived to you behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not see the problem in your script but not knowing all the directories you have, I don't know what you are facing. But something like this might help:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read dirname
do
  newdirname=$(echo ${dirname} | sed -e "1,1s/_/_adj_/")
  mv ${dirname} ${newdirname}
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Fedora, Debian and derivatives (Ubuntu, Mint, …) have installed by default a command named `rename` or `prename` for Perl version that does this for you, it works like that :

```
prename 's/_/_adj_/' *
# OR
rename 's/_/_adj_/' *
```

You can do something more complex to find and rename your files with more control like:

```
prename 's/(\d+)_/$1_adj_/' *
# OR 
rename 's/(\d+)_/$1_adj_/' *
```

Note: for `prename`, the first argument is Perl code.

Comment: _Linux_ doesn't have anything installed by default, it's just a kernel. Some distributions of software built for that kernel do have a `rename` command though. Actually, on Linux-based systems, there are two main variants of `rename`: the one coming from `perl` (or one of its derivatives) which is the one you're refering to or the one from `util-linux`.

Answer (score 0):

On non-embedded Linux systems, you can use the `rename` command, which is very simplistic but good enough for this case. To replace the first `_` by `_adj` in all the files in the current directory whose name begins with a digit:

```
rename _ _adj_ [0-9]*
```

On Debian and derivatives (Ubuntu, Mint, …), this command is called `rename.ul`. These distribution's `rename` command is a different, more powerful one which is also called `prename`; its first argument is [perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) code. To replace `_` by `_adj_`:

```
prename 's/_/_adj_/' [0-9]*
```